# How to show fields in nested documents in mongodb

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I am trying to show fields in multiples nested/embedded documents from mongodb with PHP. This is my json

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5aba47d8b57dce1e30004ad2"),
"name" : "floor58",
"data" : [ 
    [ 
        {
            "date" : 1262300400,
            "value" : 103
        }, 
        {
            "date" : 1262301300,
            "value" : 42
        }, 
        {
            "date" : 1262302200,
            "value" : 129
        }
```

I want to show the fields `date` and `value` and I've tried this code below, but it doesn't show anything.

```
$center = $database->test;
$documentlist = $center->find();

foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
    $data = $doc->data;
    foreach ($data as $values) {
        echo "$values->date";
        echo "$values->value";
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code. $valores->value. Where are you creating a var named $valores? Your variable is named $values

If this was just a typo for copy to StackOverflow, then we need to see some var_dump of your $documentlist

Comment: sorry, I forgot to tranlate that. Is already edited. It is `$values->value`
I can show you the `var_dump()` but the database is in spanish...